# Docker not seeing usb /dev/ttyACM0 after unplugging and then replugging

Tags: docker, ubuntu

I'm running a Docker container Ubuntu 18.04 which I use to compile code and flash IOT devices, I use this command: `docker run --privileged --device=/dev/ttyACM0 -it -v disc_vol1:/root/zephyr zephyr`
 To run the docker container, which allows me to see the usb devices. However if I for some reason need to unplug and replug the devices, whilst the container is still running,  docker no longer sees them, until I restart the container.
Is there a solution for this problem?

DMESG after unplugging and then replugging:

```
[388387.919792] usb 3-3: USB disconnect, device number 47
[388387.919796] usb 3-3.1: USB disconnect, device number 48
[388387.957792] FAT-fs (sdb): unable to read boot sector to mark fs as dirty
[388406.517953] usb 3-1: new high-speed USB device number 51 using xhci_hcd
[388406.666047] usb 3-1: New USB device found, idVendor=0424, idProduct=2422
[388406.666051] usb 3-1: New USB device strings: Mfr=0, Product=0, SerialNumber=0
[388406.666415] hub 3-1:1.0: USB hub found
[388406.666438] hub 3-1:1.0: 2 ports detected
[388407.881910] usb 3-1.1: new full-speed USB device number 52 using xhci_hcd
[388407.986919] usb 3-1.1: New USB device found, idVendor=0d28, idProduct=0204
[388407.986924] usb 3-1.1: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=3
[388407.986927] usb 3-1.1: Product: DAPLink CMSIS-DAP
[388407.986929] usb 3-1.1: Manufacturer: ARM
[388407.986932] usb 3-1.1: SerialNumber: 1026000015afe1e800000000000000000000000097969902
[388407.987898] usb-storage 3-1.1:1.0: USB Mass Storage device detected
[388407.988131] scsi host10: usb-storage 3-1.1:1.0
[388407.991188] hid-generic 0003:0D28:0204.00A9: hiddev0,hidraw3: USB HID v1.00 Device [ARM DAPLink CMSIS-DAP] on usb-0000:00:14.0-1.1/input3
[388407.991926] cdc_acm 3-1.1:1.1: ttyACM0: USB ACM device
[388409.014753] scsi 10:0:0:0: Direct-Access     MBED     VFS              0.1  PQ: 0 ANSI: 2
[388409.015336] sd 10:0:0:0: Attached scsi generic sg2 type 0
[388409.015632] sd 10:0:0:0: [sdb] 131200 512-byte logical blocks: (67.2 MB/64.1 MiB)
[388409.015888] sd 10:0:0:0: [sdb] Write Protect is off
[388409.015892] sd 10:0:0:0: [sdb] Mode Sense: 03 00 00 00
[388409.016103] sd 10:0:0:0: [sdb] No Caching mode page found
[388409.016109] sd 10:0:0:0: [sdb] Assuming drive cache: write through
[388409.045555] sd 10:0:0:0: [sdb] Attached SCSI removable disk
[388482.439345] CIFS VFS: Free previous auth_key.response = 00000000df9e4b01
[388521.789341] CIFS VFS: Free previous auth_key.response = 0000000071020f34
[388554.099064] CIFS VFS: Free previous auth_key.response = 000000002a3aa60b
[388590.132004] CIFS VFS: Free previous auth_key.response = 000000009bed9fb5
[388606.372288] usb 3-1: USB disconnect, device number 51
[388606.372292] usb 3-1.1: USB disconnect, device number 52
[388606.415803] FAT-fs (sdb): unable to read boot sector to mark fs as dirty
[388622.643954] usb 3-3: new high-speed USB device number 53 using xhci_hcd
[388622.792057] usb 3-3: New USB device found, idVendor=0424, idProduct=2422
[388622.792061] usb 3-3: New USB device strings: Mfr=0, Product=0, SerialNumber=0
[388622.792451] hub 3-3:1.0: USB hub found
[388622.792479] hub 3-3:1.0: 2 ports detected
```

And when I do ls /dev/ttyACM0 or /dev/ttyACM1 nothing changes when it is plugged or unplugged. The problem is that I cannot flash or see the devices with for example pyocd, when I do pycod list the devices wont show up until I restart the container.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by _docker no longer sees them_? What happens when you unplug the device (what happens with the device file in `/dev`, what is seen in the kernel log?), what happens when you plug the device in back (again - are there any changes in `/dev` and are there useful device-related messages in `dmesg`?)

Comment: I've editted the question to show dmesg after unplugging and replugging the usb

Answer (score 1):

## Problem

The problem lies in device node creation mechanism.

As you can read in [LFS docs](https://www.linuxfromscratch.org/lfs/view/10.1/chapter09/udev.html), in *9.3.2.2. Device Node Creation*:

> Device files are created by the kernel by the devtmpfs filesystem.

By comparing `mount` entries in host:

```
$ mount
...
udev on /dev type devtmpfs (rw,nosuid,noexec,relatime,size=16259904k,nr_inodes=4064976,mode=755,inode64)
...
```

...and in container:

```
# mount
...
tmpfs on /dev type tmpfs (rw,nosuid,size=65536k,mode=755,inode64)
...
```

...you can notice that `/dev` filesystem in the container isn't the same thing as it is in the host.

It seems to me that privileged docker container recreates `/dev` structure while staring. Later, kernel does create device node in `devtmpfs`, but as long as the container uses separate filesystem for devices, the node isn't created there. As a confirmation, you can notice that after unplugging the device (the one that was connected before container started), its node still persists inside container, but disappears from the host.

## Solution

You can workaround it by creating the node manually. In this example I plugged in `/dev/ttyUSB1` while container was running.

On the host machine find major and minor device number:

```
$ ls -la /dev/ttyUSB*
crw-rw----+ 1 root plugdev 188, 0 gru  5 15:25 /dev/ttyUSB0
crw-rw----+ 1 root plugdev 188, 1 gru  5 15:26 /dev/ttyUSB1
#                          ^^^^^^ major and minor number
```

And create corresponding node inside container:

```
# ll /dev/ttyUSB*
crw-rw---- 1 root plugdev 188, 0 Dec  5 14:25 /dev/ttyUSB0
# mknod /dev/ttyUSB1 c 188 1
# ll /dev/ttyUSB*
crw-rw---- 1 root plugdev 188, 0 Dec  5 14:25 /dev/ttyUSB0
crw-r--r-- 1 root root    188, 1 Dec  5 15:16 /dev/ttyUSB1
```

The device should work.

## Enhancement

You can also automate node creation by installing `udev` and writing some custom nodes inside container.

I found [this repo](https://github.com/games-on-whales/gow/tree/master/images/udevd) that successfully sets up `udev` instance inside container - `udevadm monitor` correctly reflects udev events compared to host.

The last thing is to write some udev rules that will automagically create corresponding nodes inside the container:

```
ACTION=="add", RUN+="mknod %N c %M %m"
ACTION=="remove", RUN+="rm %N"
```

I haven't tested it yet, but I can see no reason that it will not work.

## Better enhancement

You don't neet to install udev inside the container. You can run `mknod` there from script that runs on host machine (on host's udev trigger), as it's described [here](https://github.com/pbelskiy/docker-usb-sync). It would be good to handle removing nodes as well.

Comment: I wish to get it working in container. However, udevadm monitor can work but rules are not triggered (work in test so should be right).